# updating @DBref with spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

So We have a Collection with @DBRef list.

```
/**
 * List of company users
 */
@DBRef
public List<CompanyUser> companyUsers = new ArrayList<>();
```

Spring Data very intelligently insert new entries into corresponding child collection and then update the parent collection with id references whenever we call *save* on a document.

What I am trying to do is to add a child element with update call, instead of fetching the whole document, adding an element and then calling save again.

It's not allowing me to do that, I guess it tries to add the child directly and figures out that it needs reference instead and hence provides error.

Other way is to make an entry into child collection and use that id as a reference id and call update.

**But is there a way to do it in a single call with spring data when I have a child element and id of the document?**

```
public Company addUserToCompany(String id, CompanyUser companyUser) throws CimplyfiveException{
    Query query = new Query(new Criteria("_id").is(new ObjectId(id)));
    Update update = new Update().addToSet("companyUsers", companyUser);
    return modify(query, update, Company.class);
}
public <T> T modify(final Query query, final Update update, final Class<T> clazz){
        return geMongoTemplate().findAndModify(query, update, clazz);
}
```

Error :

```
Cannot create a reference to an object with a NULL id.
```

P.S - I know @DBRef was a bad idea but it wasn't my idea and I wasn't there to cast my vote against it. :D